# Transfer carte de sejour to Italian residency permit

Tags: resident-permit

We are UK nationals - retired - living in France on a 10 yr carte de sejour. We want to move and purchase a home in Italy. Is this possible using our EU residency status?

Answer (score 1):

With your French residence permit you can travel to other European countries without a visa for a max of 90 days in 180. Permanently (> 90 days) moving to Italy would require that you apply for a residence permit there.

Buying a house without already residing in Italy is only possible if your country of citizenship allows Italians to buy houses as well, luckily for you, UK is on the list.

Once you have a registered place of residence in Italy (your house) and a permanent source of income outside Italy (currently it should be > 31000€/year), you can apply for a residence permit in Italy.

Note that owning real estate property is by itself not sufficient to claim a residence permit in Italy (unlike, e.g. Spain or Portugal).